# mysql sign in with python error with SQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql

Im trying to make a sign in script in python that connects to a sql server and checks users input to see if it matches the sql server and if it does sign that account in but i getting a syntax error with my sql side of the script
Thanks :)

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root",         # your username
                     passwd="",  # your password
                     db="login")        # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor()

while (True):
    username = raw_input("Username: ")
    password = raw_input("Password: ")
    if(cur.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username =" + username + "AND password =" + password)):
        db.commit()
        print ("Logged in!")
    else:
        db.commit()
        print ("Failed to authenticate!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your username is not separated from the AND operator. The string will become something like:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username =johnAND password =1234
```

It is a very good idea to put quotes around username and password values:

```
if(cur.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username = \'" + username + "\' AND password = \'" + password + "\'")):
```

and also to use mysql_escape* functions on every string that comes from a user input and goes to a SQL query.

- I'm not sure if the escape syntax ( \' )is correct for python, it would work for C, PHP and others...

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to provide answers that teach people how to partially fix code that is vulnerable to SQL injection, without fully addressing that extremely serious issue.   Building queries by string concatenation is never okay.  Storing plaintext passwords is also never okay.